# My textbox is not displaying the data from my combobox selection

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, vba

This is my table

```
Software
-----------------
ID(Auto-Number)
ProductName(Text)
Total License(Number)
```

I'm using microsoft office access 2007 and I'm creating a form to display the above fields.

I want to display the data in total license field according to changes in combobox which select the different data in the ProductName field.

```vba
Textbox ID = TbTotalLicense
ComboBox ID = CbProductName
```

My combobox is running on a query

```sql
SELECT Employee.EmpName, Employee.EmpCode, Employee.CompanyID, Employee.DeptID,
       Employee.ComputerID, Software.ProductName
FROM
    Software
    INNER JOIN ((Computer
    INNER JOIN Employee ON Computer.CompID=Employee.ComputerID)
    INNER JOIN Application ON Computer.ComputerName=Application.[A-ComputerID])
    ON Software.ID=Application.SoftwareID
WHERE (((Application.SoftwareID) = [Forms]![Form2]![CbProductName]));
```

```vba
Private Sub CbProductName_AfterUpdate()
    Me!Softwareuserlist.Form.Requery
    Me!TbNoOfLicense.Requery
    Me!TbRemainingNoOfLicense.Requery
    Me!TbTotalLicense.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub CbProductName_Change()
    Me!TbTotalLicense = Me!CbProductName.Column(3)
End Sub
```

This is what I have code out but I keep getting error, it keep telling me to debug, it doesn't even display the data on the textbox whenever I run. My other textbox works fine.

Comment: How long is your license? Is it longer than your number column's field size permits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it is telling you to debug, then debug!

See on which code line the problem occurs. Open the locals window (menu `View` > `Locals Window`) and inspect the values of the involved variables, controls etc.

You can also open the immediate window with Ctrl-G and type an expression to be printed with

```
?Me!CbProductName.Column(3)
```

The "?" is a shortcut for `Debug.Print`

You can also set breakpoints. Klick on the gray bar on the left of a code line in order to set a breakpoint. Run the code. It will stop on that line, giving you the possibility to inspect the variables as explained above.

See:
    - [ACC: Tips for Debugging Access Basic Code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/108438)
    - [Error Handling and Debugging Tips and Techniques for Microsoft Access, VBA, and Visual Basic 6 (VB6)](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp)